# Debugging multiple Azure functions at once

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I'm currently debugging a project with multiple function apps (a function backend API, as well as a very small frontend function App that does redirects). The problem I'm having is that if I run both of them at once, using Visual Studios multiple startup projects, the debugger will fail to attach to both.

The frontend is the only one spitting out an error that the port is in use, but regardless, breakpoints on either app won't be hit.
If I run the apps individually the debugger works perfectly fine without any issues.

I also have to note that if I run both at once and have a breakpoint set, VS will inform me that symbols aren't loaded for the current file. Loading them manually doesn't help unfortunately.

Is there any way I can make this work or do I have to debug the apps separately?

Comment: I have not tried this but have you tried using two instances of Visual Studio, one for each project? You can also use the logger to write out trace information. It's a bit old school and clunky but may help.

Comment: Well I can absolutely use some workarounds to debug this, and I don't really need to debug the frontend after I've tested the bit of code running on there. A second VS instance works - but it's hardly ideal to run an entire second instance of the IDE just to debug two apps at once. This is more of a conceptual question for future reference - this project is almost out of the need for a solution.